# Python3x - Write a python script to run other python scripts?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a number of python scripts that I would like to automate using Python's Datetime and Schedule module.

They are too numerous to consider breaking apart and adding to one large file.

What is the easiest way to write a python script that will open and run these other python scripts?

I have browsed similar questions but none offered a concrete answer that I could find. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A minimally demonstrative example

In a file called "child.py", write a file to the current directory:

```
with open('test', 'w') as f:
    f.write('hello world')
```

Then, in a file called "parent.py", execute the "child.py" script:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['python', 'child.py'])
```

Now, from your command line, you can type (assuming both "parent.py" and "child.py" are in the current directory):

```
python parent.py
```

In the next instant, you should see a file called "test" in your current directory. Open it up. What do you see?

Well, `hello world` of course!

The above example makes a child of the current process (meaning it inherits the environment variables in the parent), and waits until the child process completes before returning control to the parent. If you want the child script to run *in the background*, then you need to use `Popen`:

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'child.py'])
```

Comment: Huu, your solution doesn't work for my case. I created the "parent" file as shown in your answer, called it from the correct directory, and I get a module error that my end file (a wordpress script).

`code`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wordpress.py", line 4, in <module>
    from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client
ImportError: No module named wordpress_xmlrpc
`code`

Comment: It appears that you're calling the parent script while inside an improper virtual environment. Make sure that you call the parent script while in the same virtual environment you would be in if you were to run `python wordpress.py` directly.

Comment: Thank you Huu. Your help has answered my question. If I wanted to call a py file from within a sub folder of that main folder, how would I do that?